# Saving dropdown menu selection as a cookie in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'd like to save a user selection from a dropdown menu as a cookie. I've seen this question asked before but never fully in python.
I wish to use these two cookies in running a simple piece of code so there is no need for a database to be used.

Here is my current HTML code:

```
<form role="form" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dog-names">Choose a dog name:</label>
    <select name="dog-names" id="dog-names" onchange="getSelectValue">
      <option value="rigatoni">Rigatoni</option>
      <option value="dave">Dave</option>
      <option value="pumpernickel">Pumpernickel</option>
      <option value="reeses">Reeses</option>
      <option value="{{ current_name }}"> {{ current_name }}</option>
    </select>
   <br/>
    <label>Current dog: {{ current_name }}</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Python

```
def cookies_test(request):
    template_name = 'cookies.html'
    current_name = "Rigatoni"  # default name
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'name' in request.COOKIES:
            current_name = request.COOKIES['name']
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        current_name = request.POST.get('name')
    response = render(request, 'test.html', {
        "current_name": current_name
    })
    response.set_cookie('name', current_name)
    return response
```

The python works if I give a value to {{ current_name }}
All I want is to be able to save a value from a dropdown menu in a variable so I can save it as a cookie

Any advice at all would be appreciated :)

Comment: Instead of a cookie, you could sinply store the value in the session like `request.session["selection"] = selection_value` and then when the view is called always check whether `request.session["selection"]` is present and use that value. This mechanisms uses the standard session-cookie set by Django and you do not need to set your own cookie.

Comment: I realised I never replied but thanks, the sessions worked out to be a lot easier